# Appending a link with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm trying to add a link to my page depending on what page you're already on. I'm using Squarespace to build this site, so the easiest way for me to do this would be with Javascript or Jquery.

I think there is something wrong with this syntax that i'm missing. I already tried to break out of the quotes with a \, but that wasn't working. If I'm just outputting text, it works fine, but it seems to break when I try and make it work with a link.

```
 if(loc == pageOne) {
$("#pages").append("<div> <a href=\"http://design.optimus.com/projects?currentPage=2\">Next Page</a> </div>")
    }else{
  if(loc == pageOneB){
    $("#pages").append("<div> <a href=\"http://design.optimus.com/projects?currentPage=2\">Next Page</a> </div>")
  }else{
    if(loc == pageTwo){
     $("#pages").append("<div> <a href=\"http://design.optimus.com/projects\">Previous Page</a></div> ")
  }
 }
}
```

Edit: I just checked, and the links seem to be working in Chrome, but not Firefox.

Another Edit: So the link is working in Safari too. I guess the issue now is why not in Firefox? Is there something about this method that Firefox doesn't support?

Comment: Use single quotes in your append statement and keep the double quotes (without escaping) in the text. Ex: `$('#pages').append('<div> <a href="http://design.optimus.com/projects?currentPage=2">Next Page</a> </div>')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine however you can use `else if` statements instead of nested `if` statements:

```
if(loc == pageOne) {
    $("#pages").append("<div> <a href=\"http://design.optimus.com/projects?currentPage=2\">Next Page</a> </div>")
} else if (loc == pageOneB){
    $("#pages").append("<div> <a href=\"http://design.optimus.com/projects?currentPage=2\">Next Page</a> </div>")
} else if (loc == pageTwo){
    $("#pages").append("<div> <a href=\"http://design.optimus.com/projects\">Previous Page</a></div> ")
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rba6w/

Comment: Thanks, i'll change that.

My code is working fine for me in everything but FIREFOX? I don't know why. It shows the text but it's not a link. In every other browser it links to the next page.

Comment: @patricko Then your issue is likely that your `loc` value is different in Firefox than it is in other browsers. Just before your `if` statements, put a `console.log(loc)` (or `alert(loc)`) to see what the value is in different browsers. You may want to do that with the `pageOne`/`pageOneB`/`pageTwo` variables (I'm not sure how they gets set but it's always a good idea to see what you're actually dealing with).

Comment: The loc value right now is the URL, and i'm getting it by calling
`window.location`
Is it different in firefox?

Comment: I'm getting the same URL when I alert in both Firefox and Chrome. However the link remains dead in Firefox. I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8142/discussion-between-patricko-and-jasper)

Comment: I feel foolish. All I did was add a z-index in the css, and it made the link clickable in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

see if this works

```
if(loc == pageOne) {
$("#pages").append('<div> <a href="http://design.optimus.com/projects?currentPage=2">Next Page</a> </div>')
    }else{
  if(loc == pageOneB){
    $("#pages").append('<div> <a href="http://design.optimus.com/projects?currentPage=2">Next Page</a> </div>')
  }else{
    if(loc == pageTwo){
     $("#pages").append('<div> <a href="http://design.optimus.com/projects">Previous Page</a></div>')
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Before I was getting the text at least, this doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
switch(loc)
{
case pageOne:
  $("#pages").append('<div> <a href="http://design.optimus.com/projects?currentPage=2">Next Page</a> </div>');
  break;
case pageOneB:
  $("#pages").append('<div> <a href="http://design.optimus.com/projects?currentPage=2">Next Page</a> </div>');
  break;
case pageTwo:
  $("#pages").append('<div> <a href="http://design.optimus.com/projects">Previous Page</a></div>"');
  break;
}
```